# How do I solve complicated prime factorization problems? (Ex: 20711)

Tags: prime-factorization

The prime factorization of 20711 is 139 x 149. (139 and 149 are both prime). I found this out through trial and error for a problem on one of my tests, but I don't see how to find it normally.

Comment: Divide 20711 by every number which is adjacent to a multiple of 6 (e.g., 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, ...), until you arrive at the square root of 20711.

Comment: (Or until you encounter a prime factor of 20711, whichever comes first).

Answer (score 2):

How about trying $20711=20736 - 25= 144^2-5^2=(144-5)(144+5)=139*149$?
I do not know if this is valid but this is the first technique I try: finding a square number larger than the input number and then applying $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$.
It generally works for me, though I must say prime factorisation at my level is generally done by finding all primes lower than $\sqrt n$, where $n$ is the input number.
Is this technique even valid?

**Edit:** Turns out this technique is valid and was originally used by Fermat (link in the comments courtesy Mark). Using Fermat's technique *in association* with trial division happens to be (according to Wikipedia) be faster than either of the $2$ methods individually.

Comment: The worst case scenario of this method is when the two prime factors of $x$ are $O(\frac12\sqrt{x})$ and $O(\frac32\sqrt{x})$. This is the same as any other division-trial method. It just so happen that for the specific case of $x=20711$, the two prime factors are $O(\sqrt{x})$, so your method gives a result quickly.

Comment: @goodvibration that is why I stated that it is my quick check technique. It works out at times and helps me avoid the division trial technique. When it fails... , well then back to the calculator.

Comment: In both methods (your test, and a "standard" trial) - you essentially need to try every number between $2$ and $\sqrt{x}$. What's the difference between checking if $20711$ is divisible by $5$, and testing whether $20711$ is the difference between some square and the square of $5$? In fact, the former is probably easier (for any "seed", not just $5$).

Comment: It is not always $5$.

Comment: At times you can use other squares larger than the one preceding the number. It is just like you check whether a number ends with an even number (or $5$) so that you do not have to divide by $2$ (or $5$).

Comment: This is a method associated with Fermat and is perfectly respectable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method